# Exclude one page from HTTPS via .htaccess, but redirect links on that page back to HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am using WordPress. I need to force all pages to use HTTPS, expect one specific page that has an iframe with insecure content that cannot be replaced.

I have tried many different configurations in my .htaccess file. Some of them have worked better than other, but none of them have worked completely.

The problem I'm running into is that the navigation menus on the site use relative links. I've found some options that have allowed me to force HTTP on the iframe page, but then any navigation links clicked on that page (outside of the iframe) do not redirect back to the HTTPS version of those pages.

Here is one example I've come across that doesn't quite work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Go to https if not on /iframe/
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/iframe/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Go to http if you are on /iframe/
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/iframe/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https//www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rules in your `.htaccess` file to achieve that. What this does is first check if HTTPs is not on, if not, then it will forward everything to HTTPs except for the directory `/iframe/`. The second rule checks if HTTPs is on, if so then it will redirect `/frame/` back to HTTP.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(iframe)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(iframe)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

**EDIT:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/iframe/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/iframe/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Could you double check the code? I received "The page isn’t redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: It could be because I was using `HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL`. Try my edit just below that.

Comment: The force HTTPS is working now, but it's not forcing the iframe page to HTTP.

Comment: Is there anything else I should check?

Comment: This forced SSL sitewide but did nothing for the iframe page.